# Math formula that is supposed to return whole numbers returns decimals

Tags: javascript, html, math

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    result.innerHTML += 'when "i" is ' + i + ", the result is ";
    result.innerHTML += (i + seed) * (i + seed + 1) / 2 - seed + 1 + ";<br>";
}
```

when `seed = 1;` this equation should produce whole number outputs with the first being 1, but when the code is run the first result is 5.5 and continues to mess up from there. I have checked the equation many times and worked through the problem in Desmos but cannot figure out the answer.

I have debugged the inputs multiple times, but they are the correct whole number inputs. The first result, where `i = 0` and `seed = 1` should output `1`, but instead outputs `5.5`.

The result should be `(0 + 1) * (0 + 1 + 1) / 2 - 1 + 1`, which simplifies to `1 * 2 / 2`, which equals 1, but somehow the computer doesn't calculate it this way. I used PEMDAS rules to attempt to get the correct result.

Comment: What is `seed`?

Comment: @Barmar `seed` is a number defined in an HTML number input. For my results, I made `seed = 1`.

Comment: `...+ 1 + "; ";` no clear delineation between addition [`+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition) and concatenation [`+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles I noticed that, and I seperated them and even added a .toString() but the same result occured.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles That doesn't matter because the concatenation is at the very end.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/q7k8fhun/

Comment: I'll bet `seed` is a string, not a number.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `parseInt`, `Math.ceil` or `Math.floor`.

The division will always result in decimal value (for values that are not fully disvisible like 3/2, 4/3 etc).

`parseInt`would solve your problem.

```
result.innerHTML += parseInt((i + seed) * (i + seed + 1) / 2 - seed + 1) + "; ";
```

Comment: That doesn't explain why he's getting `.5`

Comment: When you multiply a number by the number after it, the result will always be even, so dividing by 2 will produce a whole number, not `.5`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where that math formula came from, but I just declared the initial result as zero and seed as 1. The first result number I get is 01.

```
let result = 0;
let seed = 1;

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  result += ((i + seed) * (i + seed + 1)) / 2 - seed + 1 + '; ';
}
console.log(result);
```